# Android fragmentTransaction add() and fragment's onPause

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-navigation

I've implemented navigation in my Android app as one Activity and many Fragments.

When I open new child Fragment, I call this:

```
    FragmentTransaction tx = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()             .addToBackStack(null).replace(R.id.fragment_container, f)
            .setBreadCrumbTitle(f.getClass().getSimpleName());
    tx.commit()
```

This works quite well, as old fragment isn't destroyed, so when I go back in the back stack, the old fragment retains the scroll position and everything entered on it.

The problem is, in one Fragment I actually need to pause something when I add another fragment above it. I've thought that onPause() will be called, but it doesn't - I suppose that all other fragments live beneath the ones on top of them.

On the side note, I also think that my app gradually slows down as the user navigates deeper. Shouldn't I be replacing the fragment in the transaction instead, so only one is on the top?

Comment: Start a new FragmentActivity instead of adding endless Fragments on top of eachother. This will allow you to handle the lifecycle more easily and help performance. Scroll positions and such are still retained in the Fragment hosted by the FramgentActivity if you don't finish your FragmentActivity.

Comment: yeah, but should I now create 30 different activities for my 30 fragments? And what will I do when I'll want to switch to tablet layout, and have fragments side by side?

Comment: Yes, basically that is how it goes. If you want to have Fragments side by side, your FragmentActivity will have a LinearLayout with two placeholder where you can load a Fragment in.

Comment: and if I want to for example have layout (left|right): [menu|contacts], then I click contact, it should change to [contacts|specific person], then [specific person|e-mails with this person] - should I have different activities for tablet layouts then?

Comment: Try to create a smooth app following the tools Android provide. That will simplify your app both for you and for the users.

https://developer.android.com/training/design-navigation/index.html && https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sww4omntVjs&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc8j2B95zGMb8muZvrIy-wcF